# What is wrong with this question? And why is it closed by mods? Why answers don't make sense?

Tags: discussion

https://askubuntu.com/questions/291221/error-with-tar-commad-cannot-open-no-such-file-or-directory

Can Someone explain what is wrong with this question, and why any discussion is shut like that by moderators or community leaders?

I am facing this problem, extracting an archive and the tar returns these errors.
I wget the archive.
move it to a folder and try to extract it, when I extracted in home directory where I downloaded it did extract, creating a mess, but when moved same command no longer works.

```
$ tar xvf ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz
1: /home/user/bin/gzip: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

sidenote: I hope codinghorror writes more on how to live in a community or much simply, find the answers you might be looking for when you are just shut down for not having reputation or duplicate tagging, closing questions.

Comment: The tar file is present in the directory where I am trying to extract it, I used `ls`  to  determine if it is there. But now the question whose title you are answering has been taken off, I can't access it.

Comment: You can read a copy of the webpage from 2013 that you referred to at Ubuntu Pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Kbyv6zVYyw/

Comment: The questions from the title as well as the first paragraph belongs here, but as for the rest I suggest you [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) for it.

Comment: a link to  a question from 2013?!  Make a new one.By the way: we do NOT support arch

Comment: We do support extracting archives whose file name contains the name of another distro on Ubuntu though. :)

Comment: I asked the question in askubuntu with crude language, many questions general and technical in one post, the question was shifted to meta then the original question linked was 404.

Comment: thanks @steeldriver for earlier comment, I can't upvote it, not enough reputation, I didn't realise earlier I extracted it in my home directory, tar gave out some flags and ended with errors, but created all the folders, and since archive I am extracting is archlinuxARM for raspberry pi, it is a complete distro, it became evident only when I closed terminal and ran bash again with errors like `bash: /home/user/bin/dircolors: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` `bash: /home/user/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` turns out PATH made it run ARM code. So thanks.

Comment: Options sequence matters in tar command while `tar -xvfz ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz' didn't extract this did `tar -zxvf ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz` difference is how the options are sequenced. This information should be included in man pages or atleast in tutorials for `tar` This I learnt once again after facing the same extraction problems months ago, archlinuxarm archive on ubuntu machine. Then had to install bsdtar as archlinux tutorial suggested to get the job done.

Comment: The archive extracted but with errors `Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'` using `tar` I will try bsdtar.

Comment: I deleted the messed up folders in my home directory, only then could the system tar extract it in a separate folder.

Answer (score 5):

The question you link to doesn't seem to be related to the problem you are having. That question was about someone trying to run `tar` on a file that didn't exist. It was closed because the issue is trivial (you cannot do anything to a file if that file doesn't exist) and unlikely to help future visitors.

Your issue is complely different, so go ahead and ask a question on [the main site](https://askubuntu.com). Make sure to include the output of `type gzip` and `file ~/bin/gzip`.

Comment: Okay I get it now, he just copy pasted the filename from the guide/tutorial rather than actually extracting the downloaded package. "No such file or directory" error  shows for different reasons, when the -f option isn't immediately succeeded by the filename. That is how I landed on that page.